# use an arbitrary emoji as a bullet in google slides

Tags: google-slides, emoji

My team is using Google slides for presentation. Another department standard suggests using a rare unicode character, say U+1F53F Upper Right Shadowed White Circle.

Obviously one can put bullets feature at all but would be cool to use an emoji as a Google Slide bullet to benefit from automation.

I imagine it might work to export google slide to Powerpoint or openOffice format, edit on desktop and import again though I fear much of formatting and comments will be skewed.

Comment: Have you tried to simply select this emoji for the bullet list options?

Comment: I searched high and low but missed it - not sure was it available for browsing or I just did not notice. But keyword search helped

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add the tag [tag:google-slides]. What is the purpose of prepending each paragraph with the  symbol?

Comment: tag added,  looks cool and gives reader an idea how great are emoji bullets. Did I violated some policy with it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is easy

- right-click on a bullet(s)
- click More bullets
- in the search field enter the description of the symbol, e.g. Upper Right Shadowed White Circle